# cforms js datepicker inserts year twice

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, datepicker

Please test the date fields here: http://sheberesort.com.s122140.gridserver.com/contact/

You will notice the value entered once a date is chosen is not mm/dd/yyyy as it should, but rather mm/dd/yyyyyyyy.

Any ideas?

Not to mention the css is all  bonkers on the datepicker as well..

**Resolved**! Under the Global settings of the cforms plugin, the 'Date Format' field was set to 'mm/dd/yyyy'. I changed it to 'mm/dd/yy' and it now displays the date in the correct format, 'mm/dd'yyyy'

Comment: can you provide the code that you are using for adding the values in Date fields.

Comment: @kalyan it is via this plugin for wordpress- http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/

Comment: @kalyan here is a working example - http://barcelonasummercamp.com/enroll

Comment: Resolved! Under the Global settings of the cforms plugin, the 'Date Format' field was set to 'mm/dd/yyyy'. I changed it to 'mm/dd/yy' and it now displays the date in the correct format, 'mm/dd'yyyy'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Resolved! Under the Global settings of the cforms plugin, the 'Date Format' field was set to 'mm/dd/yyyy'. I changed it to 'mm/dd/yy' and it now displays the date in the correct format, 'mm/dd'yyyy'

Comment: Found the same solution just by playing with the format. Any explanation why it's working? I assumed yy-mm-dd would be 16-01-01 for January 1st 2016. Very strange

Comment: Can you explain what is cforms plugin?